# Multiplicity of a root at a given point.

Tags: complex-analysis

So we have this function $$ f(z)=6 \sin z^3+z^3\left(z^6-6\right), z_0=0 $$ and we need to find the multiplicity at the given point.. I expanded the sine function into a Taylor series around zero, and after simplifications, I concluded that the smallest power in which the variable appears is the 15th power. Therefore, we have a multiplicity of 15. The problem is that I have some notes from the professor stating a multiplicity of 3 . $$
\begin{aligned}
f(z) & =6 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^{6 n+3}}{(2 n+1) !}+z^9-6 z^3 \\
& =z^3\left(6 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{6 n}}{(2 n+1) !}+z^6-6\right)
\end{aligned}
$$ and the parenthesis be a function g(z) with $$
g(0) \neq 0\text{ .}
$$
Which one is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(z) & =6 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^{6 n+3}}{(2 n+1) !}+z^6-6 z^3 \\
& =z^3\left(6 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{6 n}}{(2 n+1) !}+z^6-6\right) \\
& = z^3 \left(6\frac{z^0}{0!} - 6\frac{z^6}{3!} +  6 \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{6 n}}{(2 n+1) !}+z^6-6\right) \\
& = 6z^3 \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{6 n}}{(2 n+1) !} \\
& = 6z^3 z^{12} \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{6 (n-2)}}{(2 n+1) !} \\
& = 6z^{15} \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{6 (n-2)}}{(2 n+1) !}. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

It is your answer, instead of your professor's, that is correct.

Comment: thanks for the answer Feather!